# Cannot delete object as it is used by override collections

Tags: objects

I downloaded a sample file to follow the Blender fundamental video, and found the objects can't be deleted, moved, rotated or scaled. What I also found is that Edit mode is locked.
How do I unlock them?
[image]

Comment: That tutorial is for Blender 2.8 and the 'all_rigs.blend' file doesn't appear to be fully compatible with Blender versions above 2.83. If you use File > Open in Blender then hit the 'N' key in the file selector, uncheck 'Load UI' and then load the file you can at least get the normal layout back, but you then get an error if you try to use the Tab key to switch views although it works from the menu! The other files with single objects in them appear to be ok.

Comment: Aha, it totally makes sense. Thank you!